# Matlab bar function for containers.Map

Tags: matlab

I want to build histogram with frequency of char entries in the string.
Matlab version 7.14.0.739
Here is my code

```
string = 'sadfjwopqiejroweifoxncvpowoirjqwerr';
map = containers.Map();
for i = 1:length(string) - 1
    if (isKey(map, string(i) ))
        map(string(i)) =  map(string(i)) + 1;
    else
        map(string(i)) =  1; 
    end
end

bar(cell2mat(keys(map)), cell2mat(values(map)) );
```

I got an error:
Error using bar (line 51)
Must supply Y data or X and Y data as first argument(s).

Error in lab4 (line 11)
bar(cell2mat(keys(map)), cell2mat(values(map)) );

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument of `bar` has to provide the x-values of your bar plot.
When you do `cell2mat(keys(map))` you just create a long string that is the concatenation of all keys, which is an invalid argument to `bar`.

Try doing something like this instead:

```
bar(cell2mat(values(map)));
k = keys(map);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(k));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', k);
```